# Jenkins pipeline: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'gitlabCommitStatus'

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

With this code i got an error in Jenkins pipeline. I don`t get it why? Am I missing something?

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

node {
    stage('checkout') {
        checkout scm
    }

    gitlabCommitStatus('build') {
        docker.image('jhipster/jhipster:v5.4.2').inside('-u root -e MAVEN_OPTS="-Duser.home=./"') {
            stage('check java') {
                sh "java -version"
            }

            stage('clean') {
                sh "chmod +x mvnw"
                sh "./mvnw clean"
            }

            stage('install tools') {
                sh "./mvnw com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:install-node-and-npm -DnodeVersion=v8.12.0 -DnpmVersion=6.4.1"
            }

            stage('npm install') {
                sh "./mvnw com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:npm"
            }

            stage('backend tests') {
                try {
                    sh "./mvnw test"
                } catch(err) {
                    throw err
                } finally {
                    junit '**/target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
                }
            }

            stage('frontend tests') {
                try {
                    sh "./mvnw com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:npm -Dfrontend.npm.arguments='test -- -u'"
                } catch(err) {
                    throw err
                } finally {
                    junit '**/target/test-results/jest/TESTS-*.xml'
                }
            }

            stage('packaging') {
                sh "./mvnw verify -Pprod -DskipTests"
                archiveArtifacts artifacts: '**/target/*.war', fingerprint: true
            }
            stage('quality analysis') {
                withSonarQubeEnv('sonar') {
                    sh "./mvnw sonar:sonar"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***Error:***

```
Commit message: "Conf Jenkins"
First time build. Skipping changelog.
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'gitlabCommitStatus' found among steps [archive, bat, build, catchError, checkout, deleteDir, dir, dockerFingerprintFrom, dockerFingerprintRun, echo, emailext, emailextrecipients, envVarsForTool, error, fileExists, getContext, git, input, isUnix, junit, library, libraryResource, load, lock, mail, milestone, node, parallel, powershell, properties, pwd, readFile, readTrusted, resolveScm, retry, script, sh, sleep, stage, stash, step, svn, timeout, timestamps, tm, tool, unarchive, unstash, validateDeclarativePipeline, waitUntil, withContext, withCredentials, withDockerContainer, withDockerRegistry, withDockerServer, withEnv, wrap, writeFile, ws] or symbols [all, allOf, always, ant, antFromApache, antOutcome, antTarget, any, anyOf, apiToken, architecture, archiveArtifacts, artifactManager, authorizationMatrix, batchFile, booleanParam, branch, brokenBuildSuspects, brokenTestsSuspects, buildButton, buildDiscarder, buildingTag, caseInsensitive, caseSensitive, certificate, changeRequest, changelog, changeset, checkoutToSubdirectory, choice, choiceParam, cleanWs, clock, cloud, command, credentials, cron, crumb, culprits, defaultView, demand, developers, disableConcurrentBuilds, disableResume, docker, dockerCert, dockerfile, downloadSettings, downstream, dumb, durabilityHint, envVars, environment, equals, expression, file, fileParam, filePath, fingerprint, frameOptions, freeStyle, freeStyleJob, fromScm, fromSource, git, github, githubPush, gradle, headRegexFilter, headWildcardFilter, hyperlink, hyperlinkToModels, inheriting, inheritingGlobal, installSource, isRestartedRun, jdk, jdkInstaller, jgit, jgitapache, jnlp, jobName, label, lastDuration, lastFailure, lastGrantedAuthorities, lastStable, lastSuccess, legacy, legacySCM, list, local, location, logRotator, loggedInUsersCanDoAnything, masterBuild, maven, maven3Mojos, mavenErrors, mavenMojos, mavenWarnings, modernSCM, myView, newContainerPerStage, node, nodeProperties, nonInheriting, nonStoredPasswordParam, none, not, overrideIndexTriggers, paneStatus, parameters, password, pattern, permanent, pipeline-model, pipelineTriggers, plainText, plugin, pollSCM, preserveStashes, projectNamingStrategy, proxy, queueItemAuthenticator, quietPeriod, rateLimitBuilds, recipients, remotingCLI, requestor, run, runParam, schedule, scmRetryCount, scriptApprovalLink, search, security, shell, skipDefaultCheckout, skipStagesAfterUnstable, slave, sourceRegexFilter, sourceWildcardFilter, sshUserPrivateKey, stackTrace, standard, status, string, stringParam, swapSpace, tag, text, textParam, tmpSpace, toolLocation, unsecured, upstream, upstreamDevelopers, usernameColonPassword, usernamePassword, viewsTabBar, weather, withAnt, zfs, zip] or globals [currentBuild, docker, env, params, pipeline, scm]
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:201)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:122)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:157)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:155)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:155)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:159)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:129)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:8)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:57)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:109)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ClosureBlock.eval(ClosureBlock.java:46)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:122)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:261)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$101(SandboxContinuable.java:34)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.lambda$run0$0(SandboxContinuable.java:59)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:108)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:58)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:182)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:332)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200(CpsThreadGroup.java:83)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:244)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:232)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Do you need to install a gitlab plugin?

Comment: @MattSchuchard I removed the following line from my file `docker.image('jhipster/jhipster:v5.4.2').inside('-u root -e MAVEN_OPTS="-Duser.home=./"')` the script run

Comment: Now is working?

Comment: @JRichardsz yes is working, but i want to deploy on a docker

Comment: mmm is resolved your initial question related to **no such method**?

Comment: could @Matt Schuchard provide comment as answer and  OP accept it?  This question can come many times

Comment: @Jayan yes it's ok

Comment: @mercer : You may answer your own question. It will help other visitors.